# Trouble accessing property of child entity within scala template in Play Framework 2.0.1

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, mariadb

I am exploring JPA and Ebean within Play Framework 2.0.1 to research what is generated in a local relational database. In my tests, I'm using MariaDB, a fork of MySQL.

So far, I've been able to successfully generate tables in the database using the JPA annotations within my models. I wanted to make sure that I learned how to set up an entity with a OneToOne relationship to another entitiy, as well as a OneToMany to another.

OneToOne: `Employee` has `Address`

OneToMany: `Employee` has `Pet`(s)

I set up a small application that allows me to quickly populate the tables, display some of the info, and delete rows from the tables. Here is the code below for those who want to see my setup:

## Routes

```
GET     /                   controllers.Application.index()
GET     /add                controllers.Application.addEmployee()
GET     /delete/:id         controllers.Application.deleteEmployee(id: Long)
GET     /employee/:id       controllers.Application.showEmployee(id: Long)
```

## Controller

### Application.java

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("entry point"));
    }

    public static Result addEmployee() {
        // Create an employee.
        Employee employee = new Employee();     
        employee.firstName = "John";
        employee.lastName = "Doe";
        employee.salary = new BigDecimal(123456);

        // Create an address for the employee.
        Address address = new Address();
        address.city = "West Chester";
        address.country = "United States of America";
        address.postalCode = "19380";
        address.province = null;
        address.street = "45 Jingleheimer Drive";

        // Create pets for the employee.
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.petString = "dog";
        Pet pet2 = new Pet();
        pet2.petString = "cat";

        employee.address = address;
        employee.pets.add(pet);
        employee.pets.add(pet2);
        employee.save();

        return ok(index.render("added an employee"));
    }

    public static Result showEmployee(Long id) {
        Employee e = Employee.get(id);
        //String s = e.address.street;
        return ok(employee.render(e));
    }

    public static Result deleteEmployee(Long id) {
        Employee.delete(id);
        return ok(index.render("deleted employee " + id));
    }
}
```

## Models

### Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long employee_id;

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;

    public BigDecimal salary;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
    public Address address;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="employee_id")
    public List<Pet> pets;

    public static Employee get(Long id) {
        return find.byId(id);
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
        find.byId(id).delete();
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Employee> find = new Finder<Long,Employee>(Long.class, Employee.class);
}
```

### Address.java

```
@Entity
public class Address extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long address_id;

    public String street;

    public String city;

    public String province;

    public String country;

    public String postalCode;
}
```

### Pet.java

```
@Entity
public class Pet extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long pet_id;
    public String petString;    
}
```

## Views

### employee.scala.html

```
@(employee: models.Employee)

@import helper._

@main("employee view") {

    <p>@employee.firstName</p>
    <p>@employee.lastName</p>
    <p>@employee.salary</p>
    <p>@employee.address.country</p>

    <p>@employee.pets(1).petString</p>

    @for(pet <- employee.pets) {
        <p>@pet.petString</p>
    }
}
```

If I render the view above using a URL like localhost:9000/employee/1 I get the following displayed in the browser:

```
John

Doe

123456

cat

dog

cat
```

Notice that the address's country is not displayed. I've also tried accessing it in the controller and printing it to the command window, which prints NULL.

However, I found that if I added getters to the `Address` class, I can retrieve it in the scala template:

Adding

```
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

...
```

to Address.java results in

```
John

Doe

123456

United States of America

cat

dog

cat
```

So I am able to set an address and assign it to an employee (it shows up in my DB). Also, deleting an employee correctly cascades and deletes the Address in the database. Likewise, this works for the Pet class which is `OneToMany`. So why do I need to add getters to access my `Address` properties, but not for `Pet`? Is my one-to-one relationship not set up correctly in the Java annotations?

Comment: Wow, really impressive job with pasting the whole required code into small window (note: this is not sarcasm!) but (there's always some _but_) would you publish your problem-project to some public repo, ie. github? Anybody who'll want to check your case for sure will not want to reproduce the app from the scratch. Anyway I'm interested in review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBean does **not** support lazy loading with direct property access.
Within Java-Controller-Code, the statement `employee.address.country` is enhanced to something like `employee.getAddress().getCountry()`. This, alas, is **not** done in Scala code, specifically not in the templates.

`employee.pets(1).petString`, on the other hand, is translated to `employee.pets.get(1).petString`, which is enough for EBean to lazy load, because an EBean LazyList is involved.

Don't stick back to getters/setters please! The Play! people argue you should know in the controller what data you need and fetch it at query time:

```
public static Employee get(Long id) {
  return find.fetch("address").where().idEq(id).findUnique();
}
```